# Set more than one pushregistry with J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, push

I want to set more than one Push Registry with my J2ME App. I have used this syntax
`PushRegistry.registerAlarm(className, totalTime);` with different time multiple times.
But getting Alert with last push-registry.

So please tell How to set multiple Push-Registry with J2ME App?